# How to check the sensor data every 0.5 seconds in Android

Tags: android, sensors

There is an `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` listener for android sensor. But this is triggered whenever this is a tiny change in the sensor data. How can I check the sensor reading every 0.5s instead of whenever the sensor data has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can not set the *interval* that the callback will be triggered since even passing `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL` parameter will cause it to trigger more than **once** every **half second**. Check the values for `SENSOR_DELAY` below.

> SENSOR_DELAY_UI      (60,000 microsecond delay)
>
> SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (0 microsecond delay)
>
> SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) (200,000 microseconds delay)

So, you will receive callbacks every *0.2* seconds and implement your way to `DoYourProcedure()`  once every *2.5* ticks.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, except that doing something every 2.5 ticks is quite hard. If you need exactly every 0.5 seconds, you will probably need to use one of the lower intervals instead (and keep track of the time instead of the number of ticks).

Answer (score -1):

use `Handler.postDelay(runnable, timeInMillis)`